# RegEx satisfying another RegEx

Tags: java, regex

In Java, what is the optimum way to check if one regex satisfies another or not?

For example:

`check("abc*","ab*")` should return `true` as second regex satisfies all the patters which are satisfied by first one, where as,

`check("abc*","abd*")` should return `false` as second regex is not able to satisfy one or more patterns for first regex, i.e `abcd`.

Also, does Java have any inbuilt method for this?

Comment: I've never heard of a function like this.  Are you building some sort of regex optimizer?

Comment: for the example you gave it would be sufficient to convert both strings into actual regexes and check if the second matches the first

Comment: @CalvinTaylor You are right Calvin, something similar to that.

Comment: @GalAbra: Referred as duplicate question determines check 'if A intersection B is null or not', where as my question in check 'if A is subset of B or not'. Checking 'A intersection B not equals to null' also gives possibility that 'A and B are to disjoint sets', Hence it's not answer of my question.

Comment: the first example is wrong `abc*` matches (`ab`,`abc`,`abcc`,`abccc`, etc.) whereas the second matches (`a`,`ab`,`abb`,`abbb`, etc.) maybe you are confusing regexp and glob-like pattern matching

Comment: What do you really want to do? Sounds like an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: @wp78de Trying to reduce set of regEx by comparing with each other.